# uwsgi: *** no app loaded. going in full dynamic mode ***

Tags: python-3.x, flask, uwsgi

wapp.py is in:

```
/var/www/KRAKEN/public/site.me/wapp
```

with the structure:

```
|-- __init__.py
|-- wapp.py
|-- wapp.ini
|-- mod_db
|-- mod_form
|-- multimedia
|-- pip-selfcheck.json
|-- pyvenv.cfg
|-- requirements.txt
|-- run_now.py
|-- static
`-- templates
```

My wapp.ini which i run in emperor mode is:

```
[uwsgi]
dir             = /var/www/KRAKEN/public/site.me
chdir           = %(dir)
master          = true
processes       = 1
socket          = /run/uwsgi/wapp.sock
chmod-socket    = 666
enable-threads  = true
vacuum          = true
virtualenv      = %(dir)
binary-path     = %(dir)/bin/uwsgi
wsgi-file       = wapp.py
mount           = /%dir/wapp/app=wapp.py
logto           = %(dir)/uwsgi.log
```

Previously the app was on the website root /var/www/KRAKEN/public/site.me, but i dont know what's going on because i updated all the pertinent config parameters, but obviously i'm missing something.
I can run the app with no errors, inside the virtual env with: `python wapp.py`

Any tips? Thanks!

Comment: try adding `module=wapp:app` or whatever the Flask application variable is called in `wapp.py`

Comment: @Busturdust the application variable is application, the default. added module = wapp:application and does not work either.